# How to chat using scokect.IO programming?

Tags: android, socket.io, chat

```
I want to send and received message in group using socket.IO.

I am using socket.IO.jar
```

My server side url(http://ec2-67-202-24-192.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3001/) I add one more class to that having UI contained button send and edit text but didn't understand that how i send and received message using below classes
  i followed this git repository
https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/tree/master/examples/chat.
1. Chat.java
2. ChatCallback.java
3.ChatCallbackAdapter.java

please any one help me in form of code that how can i complete grouped chat.

Comment: Please remove all pictures and just post the code in several code blocks.

Comment: Could you please post some code?